# Which version of the package is being used by my bundle?

Tags: java, plugins, osgi

I am working on a fairly complex server application that runs in Tomcat/WAS, etc.. It is also running in the context of OSGi.

Here is the scenario that has me very confused: (I'm slowly trying to absorb the details of OSGi).

"Bundle 1" - This bundle is managed by another group of developers and I can't touch it.  Unfortunately, it exports a certain package, call it "Package 1 Version 1".

I am working on code in another bundle, call it "Bundle 2".  This bundle includes a jar in its classpath that includes a different version of "Package 1", let's call it "Package 1 Version 2".  Also, "Bundle 2" exports "Package 1 Version 2" so that a few other bundles that I have access to can use it.

The question is which version of the package will each bundle see?
-One of the bundles, "Bundle 1" I do not have access to
-I have control over 3 bundles: 2 that need to import the "Package 1 Version 2" and "Bundle 2" that actually exports "Package 1 Version 2".

In general is it predictable which version will be selected?  My current understanding is it should work like follows:

For all bundles listed in "Require-Bundle", it will take the one that it sees first.  Therefore, if "Bundle 2" is the only bundle to occur in the Require-Bundle manifest entry, then it will use the one exported by "Bundle 2".  On the other hand, if say a bundle includes this entry "Require-Bundle:BUNDLE_1, BUNDLE_2", where BUNDLE_1, and BUNDLE_2 both export "Package 1", then the version exported by "BUNDLE_1" will win and be used.

I just wanted to check to see if this sounds correct and if anyone knows of a good source of information to figure this out quickly.  Also note that none of the bundles that I have that require Bundle 1 or Bundle 2 actually need to include an Import-Package entry since they will get access to the package simply by the use of "Require-Bundle".

So far, my testing indicates that the above statements are true, but it is not comprehensive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you should check the OSGi wiki site. There are several good articles under [Best Practices](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Category:Best_Practices) that tells about the issues of Require-Bundle. You should check the following two for sure:

- http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Use_Import-Package_instead_of_Require-Bundle
- http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Split_Packages

After reading those articles, you should check the OSGi Core specification. The resolution of bundles is described very precisely there. You should check the whole third chapter of the specification but if you want to have a very quick look about the resolution process, see the *3.9.4 Overall search order* chapter. There is a diagram there that is really self explaining.

If you are specifically interested in the resolution of *Require-Bundle*, *3.13 Requiring Bundles* chapter of OSGi core spec. is the one that you should read.

The best source is the specification itself, not google and blogs.

**For your specific problem**

It is hard to read the connections between your bundles. Probably if you shared some MANIFEST headers from the bundles, it would be easier to find out the wirings. However, the short answer is to avoid *Require-Bundle* and you will not even have questions like this.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and pointing out exactly where I can find this information!